# Google location headers failing to get details

Tags: google-app-engine

I am facing problem with Google App Engine location headers. For some reason it is not getting the details correctly.

Sometimes City/Region are coming as "?", sometimes as "unknown". At this moment Country is always "US".

Is there any particular reason for this? May be with proxy systems when users tried or something.

Please suggest on this.

Thanks in advance.